# Why am I getting 'Error type "jsonb" does not exist' in psycopg2?

Tags: python-2.7, psycopg2, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

When I run the following:

```
import psycopg2
#...
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Song CASCADE") 
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Song "
    "(songId INT PRIMARY KEY, "
    "data jsonb, "
    "lastUpdate TIMESTAMP)")
#...
```

I get

```
    Error type "jsonb" does not exist`
```

psycopg2 is installed on virtualenv, and `pip show psycopg2` gives `Version: 2.6.1`

PostgreSQL version is 9.4.4.
I can use `psql` and manually create a table with `jsonb` type column. What is causing the error when I run it through python2 and psycopg2?

I am not sure if this matters, but I just updated from PostgreSQL 9.3 to 9.4. I tried re-installing psycopg2 with pip but it did not help. I have tried restarting PostgreSQL server a couple times.

**Edit:**
When I `SELECT Version()` through psycopg2, it shows returns PostgreSQL version 9.3. How can I have psycopg2 connect to the Postgres 9.4 server?

Comment: Maybe your Python program connects to the old 9.3 installation? What do you get when you run `select version()` through psycopg2?

Comment: You're right! I got `[('PostgreSQL 9.3.9 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 32-bit',)]`. Do you know how to tell it to connect to 9.4? Also, I thought I had removed 9.3 from the system, but I guess not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that there was a config file left from Postgres version 9.3, and psycopg2 was probably reading that.

```
    :dpkg -l | grep postgresql-9.3  
    rc  postgresql-9.3                    9.3.9-1.pgdg14.04+1
```

I purged everything related to `Postgres`, deleted all config files, and reinstalled only version 9.4.

After some fiddling, `psycopg2` correctly found the server and was able to connect to it.

`[('PostgreSQL 9.4.4 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 32-bit',)]`

Answer (score 1):

i have the same. then i test

```
pavlov@pavlov-pc:/etc/apt$ sudo service postgresql status 
9.3/main (port 5432): online
9.4/main (port 5433): online
```

o! two version in different ports !

Comment: This wasn't a solution, was it?

Comment: > This wasn't a solution, was it?
yes - is's may be the cause. PG must be 9.4